# Zip large files in javascript before download

Tags: javascript, download, dojo

I have a requirement to zip together multiple files before downloading. I am using xhrget to download the file in javascript and then zipping. I can see the file being downloaded (cant find the location) in network but when I try to download the response or put it in zip, it comes out to be 0 KB.
this is happening for large files only like 1+GB. There is no error shown in browser or console.
Can anyone advise how to handle this.

```
var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
deferred.then(
        function(response){
                    zip.file(name,response);
                }
```

Comment: Hello. There is a contradiction in your question. You write "zip together before downloading", and the code snippet shows that you're downloading then adding to zip. Also, you wrote that you "see the file being downloaded", but readers don't see it. Would you mind giving more context? you can include screenshots.
Finally, the best way to get an answer is to include a reproduction of your issue, for example in JSFiddle, CodePen, or any other playground.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not making it clear earlier. I have to zip together and then download the zip. In the snippet, I am downloading the file from xhr call in javascript and then zipping all files in loop finally downloading the zip. As mentioned above, if the file is large say 1 GB in my case, the downloaded zip shows 0 kb for that file, rest all files for smaller sizes are okay. Please see the screenshots I attached.

Comment: Hi, Looks like I am not able to add any screenshots from my system in comments. I see the file being downloaded in developer tools in the network call but when the final zip gets downloaded, the file comes as 0.